# Flask can't find templates even though the file exists

Tags: templates, flask

Flask can't seem to find any files in the templates folder even though they exist. I also checked with EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING and it is looking in the right directory. This is what my folder structure looks like:

```
\myapp
  run.py
  __init__.py
  \templates
    index.html
```

This is what EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING tells me:

```
[2021-05-26 16:41:57,986] INFO in debughelpers: Locating template 'index.hmtl':
    1: trying loader of application '__main__'
       class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
       encoding: 'utf-8'
       followlinks: False
       searchpath:
         - C:\Users\...\Documents\myapp\templates
       -> no match
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo wherever you `render_template`:

```
[2021-05-26 16:41:57,986] INFO in debughelpers: Locating template 'index.hmtl':
```

Should be looking for `index.html` according to your directory structure, not `index.hmtl`!